# In excel convert into text the content of cell starting by hyphen "-"

Tags: excel, vba, format, cell, listobject

I have some text over which I perform operations and end up with a table in excel like this. The following is a screenshot of a right click after selecting a word in one of the cells.

[image]

As you see some cells start by "-"
Excel Interpreters that as a subtraction so when I edit the cell, select a word and do right click to painted red it would not let me.

After reading some answers in stack overflow it looks like this SHOULD BE  the solution:
(assuming the table shown is a listobject)

```
Dim ftstbl As ListObject
    Set ftstbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).ListObjects(1)
ftstbl.ListColumns("text").DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "@"
```

It wouldnt work.
Even performing that operation in the las line of my VBA when generating the table once I edit the cell excel does not interprete the content as text.

The behaviour that I am looking for is the following when right clicking:
As you see the blue line this time does not start by hyphen.

any ideas?

[image]
Moreover even selecting the cells > format > text excel would not let me

Comment: Add a single `'` at the beginning of the cell.

Comment: thats a good workaround.